# Computed Column Bit based on other Bit Columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, table

What would be the formula to compute a bit column from other bit columns?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee
(
[empNumb]       [INT] identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
[IsOk]          [BIT] NOT NULL, -- This is computed from other three columns.
[HasValidHours] [BIT] NOT NULL,
[NoDemerits]    [BIT] NOT NULL,
[NoAccidents]   [BIT] NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE #Employee ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Employee_HasValidHours]  
  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [HasValidHours];
ALTER TABLE #Employee ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Employee_NoDemerits]  
  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [NoDemerits];
ALTER TABLE #Employee ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Employee_NoAccidents]  
  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [NoAccidents];
```

`IsOk` would be computed from the *and*-ing of `HasValidHours`, `NoDemerits` and `NoAccidents`.

Comment: Couldn't you just run an update statement to set IsOK to 1 where the other three columns are all equal to 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean IsOk = 1 if the other three bit columns all = 1 else IsOk = 0?

If so: -

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee
(
[empNumb]       [INT] identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
[IsOk]          AS [HasValidHours] & [NoDemerits] & [NoAccidents],
[HasValidHours] [BIT] NOT NULL,
[NoDemerits]    [BIT] NOT NULL,
[NoAccidents]   [BIT] NOT NULL
);
```

See [& (Bitwise AND) (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The expression you're looking for is (regardless of whether you do a computed column or an external `UPDATE`):

```
CASE WHEN HasValidHours = 1 AND NoDemerits = 1 AND NoAccidents = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: If it's for a computed column, it probably needs a cast as well.